# Google Sheets: Hide top menu and bottom sheet tabs bar?

Tags: google-sheets

I want to be able to hide Google Sheet's menu bar at the top as well as the sheet tabs bar at the bottom when sharing the Google Sheet publicly.

`?rm=minimal` to hide the menu works perfectly. I am stuck on how to hide the sheet tabs bar at the bottom.

I tried using `&single=true&widget=true&headers=false` but they do nothing for me.

Comment: When you say you are _**"..sharing the Google Sheet publicly"**_, are you embedding the specific sheet on a website? Or you just sharing a **Published to web** link like this `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/SHEET_ID/pubhtml?gid=SHEET_TAB_ID&amp;single=true&amp;widget=true&amp;headers=false`?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to completely hide the sheet tabs bar is exporting the document as PDF/HTML.

Otherwise, the best solution would be to add **"preview"** at the end of the link and only make visible the sheet you want visitors to see.

Like this: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/123/preview

Since adding "preview" hides the sheet menu, visitors won't be able to see if there are more exisiting sheets.